# Get summernote and Lightbox working together

Tags: django, lightbox, summernote

I'm trying to write a blog on Django, this is my first experience in Django. What I want is to combine Summernote and Lightbox to get them working together in following way:

• by clicking insert image:

[Summernote panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqu88.png)

summernote inserts image within Lightbox. And it works in such way as in examples at [Lightbox home page](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/).

What should I modify and how?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To start with, this is not exactly a good solution and more of a way around. 
You can use regex to match and separate out the `<img>` tags.
Summernote stores the entered data in a somewhat similar manner to this in the database: 
 
`<p>Test content</p><p>test content</p><p> <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" data-filename="download.png" style="width: 151px;"><br></p>` 
You can separate that into parts using regex and then echo the parts out by wrapping the `<img>` tag with `<a>` tags and then give the `<a>` tags whatever class you need to get the lightbox working.You can follow the example below written in php and try writing it in python:

```
$pattern = '/(<img\s?)(src=")([^"]*)(")([^>]*)(>)/';

$string = '...summernote data like the example above...';

$split = preg_split($pattern, $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

$x = preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);

if(isset($x) && $x == true){
    echo $split[0].'<a class="lightbox-something" href="'.$matches[3].'">'.$matches[0].'</a>'.$split[1];        
}
else{
    echo $split[0];
}
```

`preg_split` returns an array with a single element containing the input string when the matching fails i.e. no img tags and hence `$split[0]`
 `preg_match` searches the string for a match to the regular expression given in the pattern. 
`$matches` : If matches is provided, then it is filled with the results of search. $matches[0] will contain the text that matched the full pattern, $matches[1] will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on.